# List of Many-To-Many relationship EF Code-First

Tags: entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I need a list of cocktails where I show all the ingredients they have,
so far I have this query

```
var cocktails = _context.cocktails.Include(c => c.Ingredients.Select(i => i.Cocktails));
```

I have a `many-to-many` relation between `Cocktails` and `Ingredients`

I think I get the ingredients but they show like this

```
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[CocktailsApp.Models.Cocktail]
```

[Front-End Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xgor.png)

This is the view

```
@foreach (var item in Model.cocktails)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ingredients)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HowTo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Also, I can get the ingredients for individual cocktails but I cant on the list.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should loop on `item.Ingredients` and take names for example, `item.Ingredients` is a reference type not a value type.

Comment: Thank so much! that solved the problem.

Comment: you're welcome, i'm glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

So you have tables of `Cocktails` and `Ingredients`, with a straightforward many-to-many relation between them, and you want "Cocktails with their zero or more Ingredients" (or some of them). You want to use entity framework to fetch the data.

If you have followed the conventions, you will have classes similar to the following:

```
class CockTail
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Cocktail has zero or more Ingredients (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients {get; set;}
}
class Ingredient
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Ingredient is used in zero or more Cocktails (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Cocktail> Cocktails {get; set;}
}
```

For completeness the DbContext:

```
class DrinkDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CockTail> Cocktails {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients {get; set;}
}
```

Entity framework will detect your many-to-many, because you have a `virtual ICollection` on both sides. Because you followed the conventions, there is no need for attributes nor fluent API. Entity framework will automatically create the junction table, and whenever you use the virtual ICollections, entity framework will perform the correct join with the junction table. Only if you want to deviate from the conventions, you need fluent API.

**Requirement:** Give me the Cocktails with their Ingredients:

```
var cocktails = dbContext.Cocktails
    .Where(cocktail => ...)            // only if you don't want all Cocktails
    .Select(cocktail => new
    {
        // Select only the cocktail properties that you plan to use
        Id = cocktail.Id,
        Name = cocktail.Name,
        ...

        Ingredients = cocktail.Ingredients
            .Where(ingredient => ...)       // only if you don't want all Ingredients
            .Select(ingredient => new
            {
                // Only the properties that you plan to use:
                Id = ingredient.Id,
                Name = ingredient.Name,
                ...
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

When using Select, you get the data exactly in the format that you want. So if you don't want a HashSet but a List, just use ToList.

> When using entity framework to query data, always use `Select` and select only the properties that you plan to use. Only fetch the complete object, or use Include if you plan to update the fetched data.

Database management systems are extremely optimized in table lookup. One of the slower parts of the query is the transfer of the selected data to your process. Hence it is wise to limit the transferred data.

If you query data without Select, changes are that you fetch more items than you actually use, especially foreign keys. The data is also copied to the ChangeTracker, which slows down the query.

One of the bonusses of using Select is that you decouple your database layout from the actually returned value. This gives you the freedom for calculations in your Select, for instance a TotalAmount, or a Count. If later your database layout changes, users of your queries won't have to notice this.